# Defining compiler directive in different file C++

Tags: c++, compiler-directives

Consider following code snippet,

```
    // header file
    #define TEXT_ENUM                //////////// HERE
    #ifdef TEXT_ENUM
        #define TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO  \
             static const char * TEXT[]; \
             static const char * getText( int _enum ) { \
                 return TEXT[_enum]; \
             }
    #else
        #define TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO
    #endif

    struct Foo {
        TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO
    };
```

---

```
   // cpp file
   #include "foo.h"
   #ifdef TEXT_ENUM
       const char * Foo::TEXT[] = { 
           "ONE",
           "TWO",
           "THREE",
           0
       };
   #endif
```

---

```
   // other_file.cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #include "foo.h"
   void bar() {
       std::cout << Foo::TEXT[0] <<std::endl;
   }
```

It works perfectly fine, but in following code it doesn't,

```
    // header file
    #ifdef TEXT_ENUM
        #define TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO  \
             static const char * TEXT[]; \
             static const char * getText( int _enum ) { \
                 return TEXT[_enum]; \
             }
    #else
        #define TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO
    #endif

    struct Foo {
        TEXT_HANDLING_MACRO
    };
```

---

```
   // cpp file
   #include "foo.h"
   #ifdef TEXT_ENUM
       const char * Foo::TEXT[] = { 
           "ONE",
           "TWO",
           "THREE",
           0
       };
   #endif
```

---

```
   // other_file.cpp
   #include <iostream>
   #define TEXT_ENUM                //////////// HERE
   #include "foo.h"
   void bar() {
       std::cout << Foo::TEXT[0] <<std::endl;
   }
```

The difference is the position of `#include TEXT_ENUM`, I get the error of undefined reference to `Foo::TEXT`. I have defined TEXT_ENUM before including the file.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: What's the difference? Can't spot it? Are you sure you're linking `.o` files  in the right order?

Comment: Your second example breaks the [one definition rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). You will have two different definitions of the `Foo` structure in different translation units.

Comment: Also, macros are defined per translation unit. Macros defined in one translation unit isn't available in another.

Comment: The position of `#define TEXT_ENUM` is different and is marked by `////////////// HERE`.

Comment: I added '#pargma warning ", Qt moc file is not expanding macro call which is strange.